# Google apps script get ranges

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a script on Google App Scripts and I want to get the number of rows that are currently in use, however with a lot of trying (and reading tutorials) they only seem to define the number rows, without actively getting the number of rows based on the sheet.

Do you how to do this best? Thanks :-)

Comment: Do you mean that on your sheet there are some empty rows? Otherwise assuming that your header is in the first row, rowsCount = sheet.getLastRow() - 2 + 1.

Comment: Check the [sheet reference page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) and look at getDataRange() it gets the range essentially from row 1, column 1 to the lower right hand corner of any data on the page.